# python 2.7: Why does IPython Notebook throw an error for non-ascii character?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm working on IPython notebook on OS X. My source code consist entirely of ascii characters. But compiler reports to me that I'm using non-ascii character. The source code looks like:

```
%%file Sierpinski_triangle.py

from turtle import *

reset()
tracer(False)

s = 'A+B+A−B−A−B−A+B+A'

l_angle = 60
r_angle = 60
for c in s:
    if c == 'A' or c == 'B':
        forward(10)
    elif c == '+':
        left(l_angle)
        #l_angle = l_angle * -1
    elif c == '-':
        right(r_angle)
        #r_angle = r_angle * -1
done()
```

---

```
File "Sierpinski_triangle.py", line 7
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file Sierpinski_triangle.py on line 7, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your minuses are wrong.

Try:

```
s = 'A+B+A-B-A-B-A+B+A'
```

[update]
Somehow SO uses a font that makes the minuses look the same. They are not. Try copying my version and your version in a text editor and see the differences.

When I run your code I get the same error as you. When I replace the minuses in your code with asci minuses the code runs fine.

What text editor are you using to create this python code? Does it has some sort of auto completion? (ms word?) If so use a real text editor or idle to avoid these problems.

to prove they are different try printing the strings as hex (copy paste in new .py file):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

your_s = 'A+B+A−B−A−B−A+B+A'
my_s = 'A+B+A-B-A-B-A+B+A'
print(":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in your_s))
print(":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in my_s))
```

gives you:

```
>>41:2b:42:2b:41:e2:88:92:42:e2:88:92:41:e2:88:92:42:e2:88:92:41:2b:42:2b:41
>>41:2b:42:2b:41:2d:42:2d:41:2d:42:2d:41:2b:42:2b:41
```

Comment: ?.. 'A+B+A−B−A−B−A+B+A' I write is same as yours.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @krishna does it look like a new question?

Comment: @RickyA in attempt to flag the answer it seems i have selected wrong option unknowingly.

Comment: @inherithandle yes unfortunately they look the same (Due to SO font), but they are not. Try copy paste them in a real text editor or idle (not ms word) and you see the difference.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It does answer it although it wasn't that obvious. Added clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the replacing standard characters like apostrophe (‘) by non-standard characters like quotation mark (`) during copying. It happens quite often when you copy text from a pdf file. The difference is very subtle, but there is a huge difference as far as Python is concerned. The apostrophe is completely legal to indicate a text string, but the quotation mark is not.